# the output between zsh and bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, zsh

i write this command in zsh

```
pwd ; ls ; cd /etc ; pwd ; cd ; pwd ; ls ; echo $BASH_SUBSHELL}
```

```
/root
Desktop    Downloads  Music     Public   Templates
Documents  for_play   Pictures  pycharm  Videos
/etc
/root
Desktop    Downloads  Music     Public   Templates
Documents  for_play   Pictures  pycharm  Videos
```

and i write it with bash

```
pwd ; ls ; cd /etc ; pwd ; cd ; pwd ; ls ; echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
```

```
/root 
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  for_play  Music  
Pictures  Public  pycharm  Templates  Videos
/etc
/root
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  for_play  Music  
Pictures  Public  pycharm  Templates  Videos
0
```

why 0 not appear zsh?

Comment: In zsh you have to use the variable `$ZSH_SUBSHELL`

Comment: Why would you expect a variable whose name begins with `BASH` to work in any other shell?

Answer (score 1):

A variable that doesn't exist in the environment doesn't have any value, so there is nothing there to print. It isn't that variables magically get the value `0`, if they are not defined, they are not defined:

```
$ echo "$sandfadsf"

$ sandfadsf=0
$ echo $sandfadsf
0
```

So, when running `bash`, the bash-specific variable `BASH_SUBSHELL` is set and therefore has a value. When running `zsh`, that variable isn't set, it doesn't exist, so when you run `echo $BASH_SUBSHELL`, the `$BASH_SUBSHELL` expands to nothing and therefore nothing is what is printed.

You can see all this with `set -x`:

```
## bash
$ set -x
$ echo $BASH_SUBSHELL 
+ echo 0
0

$ zsh
+ zsh
% set -x
% echo $BASH_SUBSHELL 
+zsh:4> echo

%
```

Comment: [equivalent for `zsh` is `$ZSH_SUBSHELL`](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2008/msg01287.html) and for `ksh93` `${.sh.level}`.